# getting/display text on external url with echo variable

Tags: php, url, variables

Im searching on google on  how to get the text of external url via php but i see a code that it displays the text on the website without adding echo and its variable. How to display the text on url with a php function `<?php echo $text; ?>` . THANKS A Lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `file_get_content()` method to retrieve the content of an URL.

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.php');
echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [file_get_conntents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) or [curl extentsion](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)